# Laravel ajax delete request

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

so here is my delete button

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-delete delete" value="{{$post->id}}">Delete</button>
```

then the ajax request

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                    $(document).ready(function(){
                         $('.delete').click(function(){
                            var id = $(this).val();
                            alert(id);
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "DELETE",
                                url: "{{route('delete_post')}}",
                                 data: { id: 1 },
                                success: function (data) {
                                    console.log(data);

                                    $("#task" + id).remove();
                                },
                                error: function (data) {
                                    console.log('Error:', data);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    });
                </script>
```

the route

```
Route::get('delete_post','PostController@getDeletePost');
```

then the controller:

```
public function getDeletePost($post_id)
{
    $post = Post::where('id', $post_id)->first();

    $post->delete();
    return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with(['message' => 'Successfully deleted!']);
}
```

so please help me identfy why nothing really happens when i press the delete button

Comment: Debug your code instead of dumping code and ask for help. Explain where it goed wrong. What the errors are you get. What the resuilt is. What the expected result is.

Comment: in your `ajax` you have `type: "DELETE",` yet the route is a `GET` request. You should change the type to `get`. Most of the time ajax queries are `get` or `post` requests and anything else is handled on the server side. Then you should change your route to `Route::delete(`

Comment: hi, so i have corrected my code but am still getting this error: Error : Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader:.ajax/v.......

Comment: could you please explain what that could mean?

Answer (score 1):

You are sending a DELETE request type in your Ajax call, which would require a _method parameter with a value of DELETE added to your AJAX data. Your route is a GET route, so that is why you are seeing no action

Another problem is in your blade syntax you are referencing a named route 'delete_post', but that is your URL, not the route name. You have not named the route from what you have posted

Try updating this line in your routes file and that should allow the request to make it to your controller method.

```
Route::post('delete_post','PostController@getDeletePost')->name('delete_post');
```

Now you have to change your Ajax request type to

```
type: "POST"
```

Comment: DELETE do exist and is a perfect valid method to use when deleting objects

Comment: True and I will edit to reflect that, but a Route::delete route in Laravel looks for a hidden _method field with a value of delete. Rather than trying to have him add another parameter to his data in AJAX, that was my suggestion but you are correct on my misleading answer that it is not valid

Answer (score 1):

I have modified you javascript, first issue in your code is,you must either use get request or post request, second issue you are not using named route in order call url for ajax like `{{ route() }}` , it should be `{{ url('path') }}` or name your route..

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                $(document).ready(function(){
                     $('.delete').click(function(){
                        var id = $(this).val();
                        alert(id);
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "get",
                            url: "{{ url('/') }}",
                             data: { id: 1 },
                            success: function (data) {
                                console.log(data);

                                $("#task" + id).remove();
                            },
                            error: function (data) {
                                console.log('Error:', data);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
```